# Display loading screen while server is generating page

Tags: database, asp-classic, server-side

I have an ASP script that generates page content in response to some GET parameters.

Sometimes the page generation takes a bit of time (running database queries etc) and I'd like to display something to the user while the page is loading. What is the standard way of doing this?

I'm not using AJAX on the page at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Response.Flush` to force something to the browser:

```vbs
Response.Write("<div id=""preloader"">Loading, please wait...</div>")
Response.Flush()
'long running code...
'long running code...
'long running code...
Response.Write("<script type=""text/javascript"">document.getElementById(""preloader"").style.display = ""none"";</script>")
```

Answer (score 3):

Is there a reason you're not using AJAX? I had a similar problem at an internship I did last summer. At first I decided to ignore AJAX, partially due to being lazy and not wanting to have to learn javascript/ajax usage. However, it became increasingly obvious that without ajax, the user experience was being significantly hampered (due to the same sort of thing you're talking about here... a longish server side operation).

If you're in the position to "AJAXify" your application, then I suppose you could add a loading image when the request is initially made, and then replace it with the given content when the asynchronous call returns. Jquery makes this kind of thing pretty easy with its various AJAX facilities and callback functions.

Of course, you're probably already aware of all of this... so please forgive me if I'm just restating the obvious!